# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'facenet_pytorch' but it seems indeed installed

Tags: module, pip, virtualenv, python-3.7

I'm in this python3 virtualenv:

```
(base) marco@pc01:~/PyTorchMatters/facenet_pytorch/examples$ pyenv virtualenvs
  3.7.3/envs/facenet_pytorch (created from /home/marco/.pyenv/versions/venv373)
  3.7.3/envs/venv373 (created from /home/marco/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3)
* facenet_pytorch (created from /home/marco/.pyenv/versions/venv373)
  venv373 (created from /home/marco/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3)
```

As far as I understand, the required module is already installed:

```
(base) marco@pc01:~/PyTorchMatters/facenet_pytorch/examples$ pip3 install facenet_pytorch
Requirement already satisfied: facenet_pytorch in /home/marco/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3
/envs/facenet_pytorch/lib/python3.7/site-packages (2.2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /home/marco/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3 
/envs/facenet_pytorch/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from facenet_pytorch) (2.23.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /home/marco/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3
/envs/facenet_pytorch/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from facenet_pytorch) (1.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in /home/marco/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3
/envs/facenet_pytorch/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests->facenet_pytorch) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in /home/marco/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3
/envs/facenet_pytorch/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests->facenet_pytorch) (2.9)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /home/marco/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3
/envs/facenet_pytorch/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests->facenet_pytorch) 
(2019.11.28)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in /home/marco/.pyenv
/versions/3.7.3/envs/facenet_pytorch/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from 
requests->facenet_pytorch) (1.25.8)
```

And with pip freeze it seems indeed installed in its virtualenv:

```
(base) marco@pc01:~/PyTorchMatters/facenet_pytorch/examples$ pip3 freeze --local
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
facenet-pytorch==2.2.8
idna==2.9
numpy==1.18.1
requests==2.23.0
urllib3==1.25.8
```

But when I try to execute this one-line-code:

prova.py :

```
from facenet_pytorch import MTCNN
```

I get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'facenet_pytorch'

```
(base) marco@pc01:~/PyTorchMatters/facenet_pytorch/examples$ python3 prova.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prova.py", line 1, in <module>
    from facenet_pytorch import MTCNN
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'facenet_pytorch'
```

- pip3 version: pip-20.0.2
- OS: Ubuntu 18.04.4 Desktop
- python version: Python 3.7.4

Update)  SOLVED:
Just installing it with pip install (not pip3) solved the problem

Marco

Comment: Did you use `sudo` command when installing `facenet-pytorch`?

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install facenet-pytorch
```

This solved the issue for me